# Unable to locate an executable at "/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/jarsigner"

Tags: java, android, flutter, android-studio, gradle

I'm trying to build a release bundle on android and for some reason, it started to give me this error:

Command:

```
flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64 --build-number=$VERSION_CODE --build-name=$VERSION_NAME
```

Error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageReleaseBundle'.
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: jarsignerfailed with exit code 2 :
  Unable to locate an executable at "/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/jarsigner" (-1)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 0s
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'... Done                        61.8s
Gradle task bundleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

I've checked, the jarsigner binary is not on that directory.
Tried to see if is somewhere installed with: `whereas jarsigner` and is located in `/usr/bin/jarsigner`

I tried to copy/symlink the file in the directory Android Studio expects it to be but once I do that and execute the build command again the **bundleRelease** task of Gradle remains at `Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'... (This is taking an unexpectedly long time.)` and doesn't finish.

I can build APK for Release without a problem.

Flutter Doctor output:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.6, on Mac OS X 10.15.6 19G2021 darwin-x64, locale en-AL)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.4)
[!] Android Studio (version 4.2)
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart-specific functionality.
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Java version outputs:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_232"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_232-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.232-b09, mixed mode)
```

I have always built an app like this, for more than a year.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I have same problem. You find solution to this?

Comment: No, not yet. Do you remember after modification you did on your computer did this issue started? Mine started after i tried to setup a React Native app and had problems with Java Path. After declaring JAVA_HOME env variable, next time i tried to build a flutter app, didn't work.

Comment: Isn't this something purely with your path, most likely setting the following in your bash/zsh profile will fix it:
```bash
# Personal scripts
PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin"
PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/ant/bin"
PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/tomcat/bin"
export PATH
```
it otherwise seems like a wrong reference to this location.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using android studio, change the JDK Location used by Gradle from embedded to OpenJDK (the one you have installed manually)

[image]

Do a clean build then. Or create a new project and copy-paste old code.